# Mostrar id que inicie en 7

Tags: sql, tablas

tengo una duda:

Tengo la tabla "ventas" con los campos:
-almacen_id
-numero_orden
-fecha_orden
-cantidad
-forma_pago
-titulo_id

Tengo que mostrar en la consulta los almacenes_id que **COMIENCEN EN 7** . Como puedo dar esta orden?? Muchas gracias

Comment: Que has intentado?

Comment: lo estaba intentando con order by, por eso estaba mal. Luego le puse el comodin '%7' y me funciono. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que seria asi

```
select -almacen_id -numero_orden -fecha_orden -cantidad -forma_pago -titulo_id 
from ventas where  almacenes_id like '7%'
```

Comment: excelente gracias!